# How to get the replication factor of C* cluster?

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I cant find it in cassandra.yaml, maybe nodetool can get me the configured replication factor of my cluster?

What is the default value of the replication factor?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A cluster doesn't have a replication factor, however your [keyspaces does](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_keyspace_r.html).

If you want to look at the replication factor of a given keyspace, simply execute  `SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;` and it will print all replication information you need.

Comment: @will- Thanks, It worked. Can you tell what is the default value of the replication factor?

Comment: There is no default value for this setting. When you create a keyspace you have to specify the replication factor.

Comment: In Cassandra 2.1, the data is in a different schema/table: `select * from system.schema_keyspaces;`

Answer (score 17):

Consider using `DESCRIBE SCHEMA` - it's likely that using `system.schema_keyspaces` will fail to work in a future version (such as 3.0+, where schema is moved to `system_schema`);

Comment: This is more updated answer than the accepted one. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

In the versions 3.0 + Cassandra you can get the RF details from the `system_schema` keyspace in the `system_schema.keyspaces` **replication** column.

```
cassandra@cqlsh:system_schema> SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;

 keyspace_name      | durable_writes | replication
--------------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        system_auth |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}
      system_schema |           True |                             {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}
 system_distributed |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}
            company |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2'}
             system |           True |                             {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}
             jerry  |           True |                   {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy'}
      system_traces |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replication factor is defined at **Keysapce level**.

In order to view the Replication Factor for a particular keyspace use the following query in cqlsh:

```
desc KEYSPACE Keyspace_Name;
```

You will get the output in which you can see the replication factor for the mentioned keyspace:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Cassandra 3.11 Version and above:

- Go to Path on Cassandra node: `cd /usr/local/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.0/bin`
- Type command: `./cqlsh` (your Cassandra node IP)
- Then Type: `SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;`

Output: You will get the replication factors of all the respective keyspaces in Cassandra

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `cqlsh` and just want to print the info from the **terminal**, use the `nodetool` and command called [describe cluster](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/describecluster.html), like this:

```
[user@user ~]$ nodetool describecluster
```

It will print very useful and brief info, including the info about keyspaces like this:

```
Keyspaces:
    system_schema -> Replication class: LocalStrategy {}
    system -> Replication class: LocalStrategy {}
    system_distributed -> Replication class: SimpleStrategy {replication_factor=3}
    system_traces -> Replication class: SimpleStrategy {replication_factor=2}
    system_auth -> Replication class: NetworkTopologyStrategy {dc1=3}
```

If you're looking for *one particular* keyspace replication info, just use the following command (in this example, we'll ask about `system_auth` keyspace info):

```
[user@user ~]$ nodetool describecluster | grep system_auth
```

..and it will print the info like this:

```
system_auth -> Replication class: NetworkTopologyStrategy {dc1=3}
```